# Como pegar o titulo de uma pagina HTML e retornar seu valor em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Preciso saber exatamente como conseguir retornar o valor do título da página:

```
<title> nome </title>
```

Retornando dessa forma:

> você está na pagina 'nome'.

Já vi uma pergunta relacionada a uns anos mas não consegui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É só usar a propriedade **`title`** em **`document`**. Também é possível usar esta propriedade para alterar o título da página.

```js
console.log(`Você está na página '${document.title}'`);    
console.log('Você está na página ' + document.title); // Sem string template

document.title = 'Novo Título'; // Alterando o título
console.log(`Agora o título da página é '${document.title}'`);
```

```html
<title>Teste</title>
```

[Veja mais em **`document.title`** na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/title).

Comment: ele está apresentando o '${document.title}' como parte do texto. mas não apresenta o titulo em si

Comment: @J.Rodrigues Provavelmente você está usando aspas no lugar de backticks (**`\``**) pra envolver a string

Comment: @J.Rodrigues De qualquer forma, isso é secundário na pergunta. Se não funcionar a interpolação, é só fazer uma concatenação simples.

Comment: valew cara agora funcionou,  nunca tinha usado essa tecla.

Comment: @J.Rodrigues Percebi que você marcou a resposta como correta e depois  desmarcou. Tem algo de errado com a resposta?

Comment: não sei o que ocorreu pois está correta, talvez um problema no app

Comment: @J.Rodrigues Acho que você tentou marcar duas respostas como corretas. Mesmo que existam várias respostas certas para sua pergunta o site só aceita que uma delas seja marcada. Acho que você não sabia disto.

Comment: desculpe, sou novo tanto na programação como no sistema do site. obrigado por me informar, manterei está resposta como correta.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que usar o javascript para isso:

Aplicando o seguinte código, por exemplo:

```
document.getElementById("seuelemento").value = document.title;
```

você atribui o valor de titulo para um campo com o id "seuelemento"

Como pode exemplo

```
 <input type='text' id='seuelemento'>
```

o código exato em javascript para voce pegar o nome do title de uma página é:

```
document.title
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função do DOM: **getElementsByTagName** e acessar o conteúdo interno a essa TAG.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML
```

A diferença é que essa função retorna um **vetor** com todos os elementos do **tipo da TAG** especificada.

E consequentemente você terá que manipular o **índice correto** daquele elemento alvo.

Comment: Isso vai retornar um "undefined". Como você mesmo citou na resposta, ele retornará um "vetor", portanto, para capturar o valor da `tag`, deverá passar a "index". O correto é `document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML`

Comment: Sim, correto. É que como citei vetor, pressupõe que de alguma maneira terá que manipular índice. Irei fazer a edição necessária para melhorar a resposta. 
Obrigado.